# BASH/Linux: Always Up or Retry a command?

Tags: bash, persistence

For my particular use case, I liked to use `docker-compose up` to provide retry logic for a couple of apps.

When shifting gears and pivoting to easy to use CDN infrastructure, it seems as if running shell commands to start everything up in a single docker container will be simpler.

However, the only thing I have found that corresponds to anything like "always up" logic is:

```
while true; do start-app || sleep 1; done
```

What I was curious about was if there is truly some sort of Unix/BASH 'retry' tool that will make sure a command is always running in addition to whatever the useful features there are for that kind of system-level operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use systemd

Create a file for example `/etc/systemd/system/yourapplication.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Your Super application
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

StartLimitIntervalSec=500
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

ExecStart=/path/to/application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Or the oldy way is to launch your application using init.

Add to init script a line

```
ap:2345:respawn:/bin/sh /somewhere/start-app
```

With `ap` the id of your service (max 2 letters)

`2345` Lists the run levels to which this entry applies.

- 2 Multi-User Mode Does not configure network interfaces or start daemons.
- 3 Multi-User Mode with Networking Starts the system normally.
- 4 Undefined   Not used/User-definable
- 5 X11 As runlevel 3 + display manager(X)

`respawn` for the action

then the command to run